# DialogFragment not seen as visible when created with onCreateDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

(Using the compatibility library)

I have implemented a dialog with extends DialogFragment.
I create the dialog using AlertDialog.Builder in onCreateDialog (onCreateView is not used).

In my fragment I invoke the dialog with:

```
dlg.show(getFragmentManager(), tag);
```

However, when I come to check visiblity, once the dialog is clearly visible, using

```
dlg.isVisible();
```

This returns false.

Now the following is the Fragment::isVisible code from the compatibility sources.

```
final public boolean isVisible() {
    return isAdded() && !isHidden() && mView != null
            && mView.getWindowToken() != null && mView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

The calls returns false because mView is null because the view isn't attached to a window.

Any ideas as to how I should be invoking the dialog, or creating it for that matter, so that it is attached to the fragment's root view? Or how else I should be checking for visibility?

Thanks in advance, Peter.

Comment: I have managed to work around this by adding my on visible() method in my DialogFragment subclass and then calling 'isShowing()' on the AlertDialog that I return in onCreateDialog(...). Surely I shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Now, u can detect DialogFragment is showing or not? Can update the answer please?

Comment: Have I provided an answer than needs updating?

Answer (score 4):

You can determine if a dialog fragment is showing by a function like:

```
boolean isShowing(DialogFragment dlg)
{
   return dlg.getDialog() != null;
}
```